# Is it possible to create a twitter like 'reply' or 'retweet buttons that appear on hover only using CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create some buttons like this[image: twitter hover buttons];

They're inside a link with display block, and appear only on hover. How can i do this with css only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way would be something like:

```
#thing{
display:none;
}

#thing:hover{
display:block;
}
```

You could put on your fancy-pants and add some transitions to gussy it up but then you couldn't use display:none;

Comment: I don't understand , could you please elaborate on how to do this ?